# How to ask for the permission to become Default Video Player in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video, android-video-player

I am developing a video player app and I want my app to Prompt for the permission to be the default Video Player to be the **default handler** of video play.
I know it has to be something like the default handler:

```
Intent setSmsAppIntent =
    new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
setSmsAppIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
    getPackageName());
startActivityForResult(setSmsAppIntent, your-result-code);`
```

source: [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers)

But I don't know the Action I have to give to the Intent as action. Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, developers can't call intent to change default Video player only users can do that on their device. Its only possible for `SMS service`.

However, for video player you can register app for video player in `AndroidManifest.xml` and call the function which opens settings to change default apps using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, @prafful-lachhwani for your reply. When I go to Default App Settings I can only find [Assistant, Browser, Home, Phone, and SMS app) Options for Default apps, there is no option for Video Player.